# Why is time-localization not captured by standard Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The standard Fourier Transform
\begin{equation*}
    (\mathcal{F} f)(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int d t e^{-i \omega t} f(t)
\end{equation*}
gives a representation of the frequency content of $f(t)$ but no information about the time-localization. I read this sentence in a book (the popular book by Daubechies, "Ten Lectures on Wavelets") but... why? I would like to read an example that explain in detail this sentence.

Comment: This is not a really formal mathematical statement. Since you can invert the Fourier transform, you can get back $f$ from it, so the Fourier transform**uniquely determines** the time-localization. What is meant is that by just looking at the Fourier transform (and not doing complicated things like inverting it), it is not **easily** possible to see how well $f$ is localized in time (or behaves in time). Some things about the time-localization can actually be read off somewhat easily; see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem

Comment: @PhoemueX: thank you. Now it is clearer to me.